# Why is Qt losing my thin space unicode character when loading an XML file?

Tags: xml, qt, unicode

I have an XML document, part of which has the following in it:

```
<math display='block'><mtext>&#x2009;</mtext></math>
```

If this is loaded into Qt (specifically the Qt MathML widget where I found this problem), the QDomDocument object loses the unicode thin space character (U+2009). This Python example code demonstrates the problem:

```
from PyQt4.QtXml import *

d = QDomDocument()
d.setContent("<math display='block'><mtext>&#x2009;</mtext></math>")
print repr(unicode(d.toString()))
```

The output from this code is:

```
u'<math display="block">\n <mtext/>\n</math>\n'
```

Inserting an extra non-space character after the thin space stops the thin space being lost.

Is this my mistake, an XML feature, or does Qt have a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [QDomDocument's documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html):

> Text nodes consisting only of whitespace are stripped and won't appear
>   in the QDomDocument. If this behavior is not desired, one can use the
>   setContent() overload that allows a QXmlReader to be supplied.

So this way you do not lose the white space only data (example is in C++):

```
QXmlSimpleReader reader;
QXmlInputSource source;
QDomDocument dom;

source.setData(QString("<mtext>&#x2009;</mtext>"));
dom.setContent(&source, &reader);
```

Comment: Hm-m-m. Except that &#x2009; isn't whitespace. The XML rec says that only "space (#x20) characters, carriage returns, line feeds, or tabs" are whitespace.
The rec also says, "A special attribute named xml:space may be attached to an element to signal an intention that in that element, white space should be preserved by applications." 
So if QT is treating &#x2009; as whitespace, it might be simpler for @xioxix to alert the XML processor thusly:
`<math display='block'><mtext xml:space="preserve">&#x2009;</mtext></math>`

Comment: Well, QDomDocument handles that thin space character as a white space and not according to XML specification. And QDomDocument does not seem to support the xml:space attribute. So xioxox could [make a bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa). While waiting for the fix, the `setContent()` using QXmlReader works.

Comment: Thanks - I'll accept this as the solution, and file a bug report!