# How to set QLineEdit default text to one space?

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I entered one space as a `QLineEdit`'s text in the Qt Creator GUI Designer. I can see that the space is there in the designer wiew, but if I compile and run it, the space disapears. I want this space to be a `QLineEdit`'s default text, how can set it, or tell Qt to do not delete that one space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My guess is that space disappears because UIs are stored as XML and nodes consisting only of whitespace are strippd ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968940/why-is-qt-losing-my-thin-space-unicode-character-when-loading-an-xml-file)).

But you can set the space to the QLineEdit in the window's constructor:

```
ui->lineEdit->setText(" ");
```

Answer (score 8):

If what you want is to have a default text when the widget is empty, use the [setPlaceholderText(QString)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop)

If you want to just set a initial value, then do it in the constructor of your app/widget/class with [`setText(QString)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop)