# How can I read whitespace-only elements into QDomDocument?

Tags: xml, qt

When `QDomDocument` reads XML elements that consist only of whitespace, it reads an empty element. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10970525/1447002) provides a solution to the problem, using `QXmlSimpleReader` , and `QXmlInputSource`. But these classes are now deprecated (at least as of Qt 5.15).

The docs for `QDomDocument::setContent` now recommend using `QXmlStreamReader`. But when I do this, I again lose my whitespace:

```
QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(&file); /// successfully-opened QFile

QString errorString;
int line, column;
bool result = mDomDocument->setContent(&xmlReader, false, &errorString, &line, &column);
if( ! result )
{
    qCritical() << "XML Read Error, Line " << line << ", Column " << column << ": " << errorString;
}
```

From the above I get no warnings, and no whitespace.:-)

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-104130) (or undocumented feature) and [will apparently be fixed](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/415926) in Qt 6.5.